# Truncate longer text-chips before shorter will be truncated

Tags: css, flexbox, truncate, ellipsis

I have a list of countries, i.e., Afghanistan, Chile, Saint Vincent and the Grenadines. They all are placed in a chip with a max-width. If the length of the list reaches the max-width, the country names should be truncated with ellipses.
This means the country Saint Vincent and the Grenadines should be truncated first and Chile last.

So the question is, how to resize longer elements first before shorter will be resized? If shorter elements reach their needed space, the longer elements can use the rest of the space, with pure CSS.

I tried it with flex-box but in this case all countries will be truncated based on their width ratio. I also tried to give all countries the same width, but shorter countries have empty space at the end.

Here's the current result:
[image: Current Result]

Here's my code:

```
<div class="chip">
  <div class="criteria">Country</div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"><p class="name">United Kingdom</p></div> 
    <div class="item"><p class="name">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="name">Chile</p></div> 
  </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.criteria:after { content: ":"; }

.items {
  margin-left: 4px;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 220px;
}

.item {
  min-width: 0; display: flex;
  
  .name {
    white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; margin: 0; padding: 0;
  }
  &:after {
    content: ","; padding-right: 4px;
  }
  &:last-child:after { content: "" }
}
```

You can see a more advanced example on Codepen: https://codepen.io/Densagined/pen/wvNNwbz

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I don't have enough experience myself, so I can't give you a final answer, but have a look at the property [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) and `flex-basis` and their use in the shorthand `flex`. They allow you to determine when a flex element is allowed to shrink.

Comment: I already tried, but this is not the solution. `Flex-base` needs to be set to auto because the length is dependent on the length of the word (i.e. Country name). And `flex-shrink` shrinks all items in same ratio. But first longer items should shrink BEFORE shorter items will shrink.